# Best way to read a file from a url when it got changes?

Tags: php, node.js, ubuntu

Let's suppose i have a url http://localhost/test.csv (approx 10M). It may be in any format csv, tsv or log. I want to download that file as soon as it got some changes. I can scrap it on very low frequency but that is a worst case. I want to know is there any better way to solve this.

Comment: If it's on a remote website, you'll have to download it every time to check if the contents differ from what you had previously. There is no other way as remote files like that don't save metadata about creation or modification dates.

Answer (score 0):

Forge the request with the header [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since).
In this way the server will send back the requested resource, with a 200 status, only if it has been last modified after the given date